# JS: use grunt + mocha + phantomjs

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, phantomjs, mocha.js

I used the yeoman `webapp-generator` to create a fancy website template. It creates a test-folder and scaffolds the whole project incl. one simple unittest. To try the phantomjs functionality I added an additional function:

```
describe("DOM Test", function () {

    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.id = "myDiv";
    el.innerHTML = "Hello World!";
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    var myEl = document.getElementById('myDiv');

    it("has the right text", function () {
        (myEl.innerHTML).should.equal("Hello World!");
    });
});
```

But when I run `grunt test` I always get this annoying error:

```
Running "mocha:test" (mocha) task
Testing: test/index.html

Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

My mocha-entry within the Gruntfile looks like this (its a slightly modified version of the generated one. I replaced the url by a relative path with wildcard):

```
mocha: {
      test: {
        src: ['test/**/*.html'],
      }
    },
```

And the `test/index.html` looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Mocha Spec Runner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mocha"></div>
    <script src="bower_components/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
    <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
    <script src="bower_components/chai/chai.js"></script>
    <script>
        var assert = chai.assert;
        var expect = chai.expect;
        var should = chai.should();
    </script>

    <!-- include source files here... -->

    <!-- include spec files here... -->
    <script src="spec/test.js"></script>

    <script>
    if (window.mochaPhantomJS) { mochaPhantomJS.run(); }
      else { mocha.run(); }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And I tried the following things (without success):

- run bower twice (suggested by [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501320/failing-to-setup-a-test-environment-with-grunt-phantomjs-and-mocha))
- added `grunt.config.set('server.port', 7002)` ([suggested by this github issue post](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/719))

Answer (score 2):

Go to your test folder and run `bower install`:

```
cd test
bower install
```

Then try again to run `grunt test`.

You have two bower_components folders, one in root and one in test.